# what does the term magnification mean on a pair of binoculars?

Tags: optics, everyday-life

I bought a pair of binoculars for astronomy, which are described as $12 \times 36$, with the $12$ being the magnification. However, when I look at, say the Moon, it doesn't appear to me to be $12$ times larger. Also, shouldn't the image be $12^2 = 144$ dimmer (if the image really was $12$ times larger)?

Answer (score 1):

If you *measured* the size of the image with and without the binoculars, it would indeed be 12 times the diameter. However, in real life you can't easily do that, and when the moon is high in the sky there is nothing available to compare its size with, so its *apparent* size depends mainly on how your brain interprets what it is seeing, not on some absolute measurement unit. (*)

The image isn't $12^2 = 144$ times dimmer, because the binoculars are collecting all the light that falls on a bigger area (i.e. a 36mm diameter circle) compared with the pupil of your eye which would probably be around 3 or 4 mm diameter when looking at a full moon.

(*) For example, the moon often *appears* to be bigger when it is close to the horizon, because familiar objects like trees, houses, etc are often available for comparison, and you "know" the moon is much further away than those objects, so it "must be" very much bigger than they are. But if you compare the apparent size of the moon with a consistent reference object, for example a coin held at arm's length, you find its apparent size is the same at any position in the sky.